# Testing Significance of Difference in Single Store Sales Data - Today's sales vs. Moving Average

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance

When reviewing sales data for a single store, what is the most appropriate way to test whether today's total sales value is statistically different from the 30 day moving average of the company's sales?

What's throwing me is that that data is sales for one store, I am not testing whether the sales between multiple stores is significantly different.

Comment: You might want to look at control charts, specifically moving average charts.

Answer (score 1):

As per the statement, you are keen to see whether today’s sales is different from past  30 days average. It is more appropriate to use the average of actual sales data rather than the average of moving average data. You can also find out the 95% conference interval of past 30 days data. If your present data falls into it than conclude that the present day’s sales is not significantly different. Otherwise it is significantly different. This is a simple way. Another way could be to use t test  with single mean. Treat past 30 days average as population mean and present days sales as sample mean. Then go ahead. Significant t test would reveal present mean is significantly different from that of past 30 days mean.

Comment: Thanks and appreciate the input. The reason I am using moving average is that daily sales of a single store fluctuates greatly. A Monday's sales is a lot different to sales seen between Thursday and Saturday, so there is a lot of noise. I like the idea of the 95% confidence interval. Can I ask one thing regarding the t test, would the assumptions be met with this use case?

Answer (score 0):

Unless they're equal, they are statistically different. Your selection of the threshold for statistical significance is going to determine whether or not it (somewhat arbitrarily in this case of just a single store) is significantly different. Are you actually doing this for many stores, looking at each one individually vs its recent average? @Ramnath Takiar gave several ways you could do the test. You could also just use a simple % or nominal value (if it is +/- $150, or +/- 10%).

Comment: Yes doing this for many stores and looking at each one individually. The nominal value is what I am doing at the moment, I have been thinking of testing significance as one business might think a 5% change is a significant change  but another might think a 10% change is. Cheers for the suggestion